# Regarding Professional Report

Tags: technical-writing, business-writing

I am new in the working world and I happen to be given a lot of tasks related with creating report.

Later on I heard people give me comments that my sentence structure and my word choices are not professional enough (in a corporate world).

I start to think that I need to improve this. Can anyone suggest/advice me tips on how to be professional in writing? If you have some websites to recommend, it will be nice too.

Several mistakes that I am usually critized:

1. Word choices are too simple and not specific
2. Lengthy and shorty sentences
3. Usage of first person in the sentence
4. I don't utilize several strong ms word features that actually ease report making, can someone suggest me on this?

Comment: This is too broad and too vague of a question. If you can post a specific example of your writing and ask for suggestions on how to improve ONE aspect of it, we can help. Also, please specify what language you are asking for help writing in, and whether it is your native language, because those matters will make a difference.

Comment: What are "shorty sentences"?

Comment: You know, sentences about your shorty (hip-hop slang for your girlfriend).

Comment: Hilarious: your question on how to learn to write better, sparked from your inability to communicate via writing, is closed because you did not communicate effectively in written form. -- Oh, and go to a local community college and take an English Composition course. Report writing is one thing, but you need to go learn the foundations of English first. Your post is painful to read.

Comment: Patches: Rofans is from Maylasia. English may not be his/her first language. Put sugar in what you say and salt in what you hear.

Comment: Fair enough. I should have left off the "painful to read" bit.